# Using image files with webpack 5 and react, webpack is processing the image but it won't load in the browser

Tags: reactjs, image, webpack

I'm trying to add a PNG image to a web page, I'm using webpack 5.15.0 and React. When I bundle I see a new file in the root directory displaying my image with a filename like "5e3455bfee8acb9fe3fe.png", which I think means it's being processed correctly by webpack. But it's just showing up as a broken image in the browser with a 404 error in the console.

For reference, my webpack config file looks like this:

```
 entry: [
   './client/index.js'
 ],
 output: {
   path: __dirname,
   filename: './public/bundle.js'
 },
 devtool: 'source-map',
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.jsx?$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       loader: 'babel-loader',
       options: {
         presets: [
           '@babel/preset-react'
         ]
       }
     },
     {
       test: /\.png/,
       type: 'asset/resource',
     },
   ]
 }
}
```

and the file where I'm using the image looks like this:

```
import myImage from "../../assets/myImage.png"

export const Home = () => {

  return (
    <div>
       <img src={myImage}></img>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper loader to handle images with webpack. Here is a working solution to handle all your assets (images & fonts). Install `file-loader` as a devDependency, and add this line to your `rules` array:

```js
 { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|woff2)$/, use: ["file-loader"] },
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, however that did not have any effect. Per the webpack docs though it looks like they replaced loaders with asset modules in webpack 5 https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/